# Automatic sign-out when cookies expire (Blazor Server + AWS Cognito + OpenIDConnect)

Tags: cookies, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, blazor-server-side

Good day,

I cannot find a way to sign out user automatically when cookies expire. I am using Blazor Server with OpenIDConnect and AWS Cognito.

**Program.cs**

```
// Configure SignalR to close the connection when the authentication token expires
app.MapBlazorHub(options =>
{
    options.CloseOnAuthenticationExpiration = true;
});
```

this closes SignalR connection when cookies expire (all good) but because I am using OpenIDConnect with AWS Cognito it fails to sign out user properly. Once the SignalR connection is closed, in a split of a second, automatically, user re-establishes a new connection on the same page and is given new cookies. User stays on the website forever.

I created a new service called **CustomCircuitHandler** which could capture event when circuit is closed.

```
public override Task OnCircuitClosedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Implement logic to identify specific user and take actions
    Console.WriteLine($"Circuit closed for user: {circuit.Id}");

    // Navigate to sign out page
    // NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/logout");

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

only if I could navigate user to /logout page, everything would be fine. This service does not have HTTP context that provides PageModel.

Logout page code (**/logout**):

```
public class LogOutModel : PageModel
{
    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = "/"
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem of application when the front page is the login page.
There are two ways out of this:

- Have a logout page which is not the FrontPage
- Have a login button to trigger the authentication on the front page

If you are using your own UI for authentication with Cognito (which I assume is) Cognito does not maintain session and therefore it is a cookie management problem in your app for your session. Maybe you miss a cookie setting with expiry set to January 1st 1970 to invalidate it.

If you are using the Cognito Hosted UI, know that Cognito is keeping track of the session with a cookie for 1 hour to allow SSO in between multiple applications. To Logout of Cognito you need to call the Logout endpoint with an Access Token: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html